# Testcafe close window

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have this simple page that opens a new window.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="open">Open window</button>
    </body>

    <script>
        var windowObjectReference;

        function openRequestedPopup() {
        windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.cnn.com/", "CNN");
        }
        document.querySelector("#open").addEventListener("click", openRequestedPopup);
    </script>
</html>
```

I also have this test:

```js
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';

fixture `Close window`
    .page('http://127.0.0.1:8080/');

test('Close window', async t => {
    await t.click("#open");
    await t.switchToWindow(f => f.url.host==="www.cnn.com").closeWindow();
});
```

When trying to find the window based on a predicate the test fails

```
PS C:\work\New folder> testcafe edge .\test.js
 Running tests in:
 - Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.43 / Windows 10

 Example page
 × Close the current window

   1) Cannot find the window specified in the action parameters.

      Browser: Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.43 / Windows 10



 1/1 failed (5s)
```

I am not able to understand what should I do in order to get hold of the window oppened from js code.

How can I get the window and inspect some elements inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have fixed issues related to "Multiple browser windows" mode. Please install the current alpha version (`npm i testcafe@alpha` / `npm i testcafe@1.17.2-alpha.2`). Also, you need to fix your predicate's `host` value. The actual hostname of this CNN page is `edition.cnn.com` (you can check it without TestCafe by observing the `window.location.hostname` property in the browser console):

```js
await t.switchToWindow(f => f.url.host === 'edition.cnn.com').closeWindow();
```

Alternatively, you can use [`t.getCurrentWindow`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402699/reference/test-api/testcontroller/getcurrentwindow) instead of the predicate:

```js
await t.click("#open");

const cnnWindow = await t.getCurrentWindow();

await t.closeWindow(cnnWindow);
```